# Find activities which have versions not delivered into production

Tags: android-activity, clearcase, baseline

How do you find activities which have versions not delivered into production (or in some baseline) in UCM Clearcase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to get that information.
You need to:

- list all the activities
- '`cleartool descr -fmt %[activities] baseline:MyBaseline@\myPVob"`'
- compare the two.

The general issue is that you cannot limit the baselines you know to be in production, because a baseline is based on its predecessor, and only the predecessor can list its activities.

---

One other solution would be to use **`cleartool diffbl --act`**, comparing the current baseline with the very first baseline of a component.
That would list all the activities part of the current baseline and part of its predecessor.